# Generalized Memory Polynomial in Digital Pre-Distortion

Tags: power-amplifier, distortion

I am currently trying to understand the concept of Generalized Memory Polynomials used in Digital Pre-Distortion and I wanted to seek some answers for some questions that were bothering me. The form

\begin{align}
y_{GMP}(n)=&\sum_{k\in K_a}\sum_{l\in L_a}a_{kl}x(n-l)|x(n-l)|^k\\
 + &\sum_{k\in K_b}\sum_{l\in L_b}\sum_{m\in M_b}b_{klm}x(n-l)|x(n-l-m)|^k\\
 + &\sum_{k\in K_c}\sum_{l\in L_c}\sum_{m\in M_c}c_{klm}x(n-l)|x(n-l+m)|^k
\end{align}

which is given in the formula for the GMP is the output we want after pre-distorting our signal and passing it through the Power Amplifier, but what's not clear is how we would solve for \$x_{GMP}\$ such that \$x_{GMP}\$ at the input of the power amplifier will give us the required ACPR or whatever optimality we're expecting at the output.

My concern was really how to approach it. Like we have \$y_{GMP}\$ that estimates the non-linearities of the Power Amplifier so if we find the coefficients \$a_{kl}, b_{klm}\$ and \$c_{klm}\$ (which I'm not sure if we really need to solve for them) how would we then solve for \$x_{GMP}\$ (which I'm almost certain has its own set of coefficients)?

Answer (score 0):

You need a non-linear equalizer / predistorter.

So, that's not a  problem with one "best" solution, and it's not even a problem with a correct solution, as you simply cannot invert every nonlinear channel. Bad luck!

But the way you're approaching this shows excellent understanding:

- you understand this as a optimization problem over some optimality metric

  - hence you understand that it depends on the metric what kind of approach you take to solve this
- you understand that finding the coefficients of your GMP model (*system identification*) is not inherently the same as finding the optimal way of preventing them (*equalization*/*predistortion*)
- and you understand that your predistortion coefficients are not the same as the channel coefficients

So, as you're saying "I am trying to understand the concept", you're absolutely on the right path :)

So, all I can do is shove you in a few directions, not being an expert on these methods myself:

- This problem occurs not only in power amplifiers, but also in optical communications, where not only amplifiers, but the fibers themselves have memory and nonlinearities. So, don't be afraid to look up stuff in the optics domain, even if your amplifier is just electronics ;)
- There's a solid chance that you know of one way to find a system, that, when combined with another system, and fed with some random input, has the desired properties. And that's neural network: You know you want to find some function (*predistorter*) that takes an input signal, and outputs a predistorted signal, which, when put through the GMP model, has some measurable and quantifiable qualities. As per the *universal approximation theorem*, neural networks can approximate any function (given they have enough neurons with nonlinear activation functions). You can easily generate arbitrary amounts of training input signals, and your "ACPR or whatever" makes for your training loss function. 
  It's still not a trivial problem, because the search space for an appropriate predistorter is large, and you can't use something with an extremely high number of neurons (thus: coefficients) in practice, you need to be fast at adapting to changing channels, and it's not clear what the architecture of your net should look like. Thus, people with domain knowledge are working on finding NN-based equalizers for optical communications. I don't know how well this translates to predistortion for PAs, but honestly, I found this paper of my colleague nice to read:  *Lauinger, Vincent, et al. "Blind and Channel-agnostic Equalization Using Adversarial Networks." arXiv preprint [arXiv:2209.07277](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.07277) (2022); you'll find more by Lauinger and his professor, Schmalen, on the topic, but I think this gives a neat idea.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response, was unwell this past week. I do think neural networks are 1 possible solution, my only concerns were with the feasibility in my case. To expound, my solution would be being implemented on an FPGA and I doubt it would be able to handle a neural network on board. However, the paper you linked does implement an equalizer despite the use of neural networks which that can at least assist in further piecing together my model and I may resort to classic algorithms like least squares and maybe Cholesky decomposition for the non-linear equations. Thx for the help tho:)

Comment: Hi! Well, you don't have to *train* it on the FPGA, but in general, FPGAs are quite well-suited architecturally for implementing Neural Networks.

Comment: hey, just wanted to give an update. Made loads of progress over the last year in getting the inverse for my system and in the process I heavily refined my unerstanding of the problem. I made so much progress that I went into optics funnily. I'll most definitely switch to NN's if push comes to shove.
In any case, thanks for answering my question a year ago as I would've been a bit more lost without the assistance.

I had a question though. With all the need for "AI"in today's day and age, why the push for GPU processing instead of FPGA processing?

Comment: Efficiency. A bunch of hard multiplier cores (and other nonlinear functions) as well as memory bandwidth is what you need. And GPUs are *exactly* that! If you wanted to configure an FPGA in a way that it becomes a good accelerator for general neural networks (and not just one specific architecture), then you'd end up architecting pretty much a GPU, just that the GPU's elements are much smaller and more power-efficient.